# Solving 1st order PDE via the method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I have the following PDE

$$\left(x^2 + 1 \right) u_x - x y \, u_y = 0$$

I tried to solve it, but I know I'm getting the wrong answer. The following is a photo of my solution. Can someone help me, please?

[image: my solution]

Comment: @JJacquelin so you mean c= -(ln(y)/x)-arctan(x)?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it is actually a part of the original PDE, which is: (x^2 +1)*u_x-xy*u_y+2x*u=-1

Comment: Integrate $\frac{x\:dx}{x^2+1}=-\frac{dy}{y}$. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: On your joint page the fourth line is false.

Comment: Please consider MathJax'ing your solution.

Comment: @JJacquelin, ok so that means c=-ln(y)-(1/2)*ln(x^2+1)?

Comment: $$u\! \left(x,y\right)=f_{1}\! \left(y \sqrt{x^{2}+1}\right)$$

Comment: @gpmath this is exactly the answer I get from Wolframalpha. Can you please explain  the approach to get this answer?

Comment: Try characteristic strip method for first order PDEs.

Comment: @JJacquelin. I get u(x,y)=f(-ln(y)-ln(1+x^2)/2), this solution satisfies the PDE. Thank you!

Comment: Note that $f(-ln(y)-\frac{1}{2}ln(1+x^2))=f(-ln(y \sqrt{1+x^2}))=f(g(y \sqrt{1+x^2}))=f_1(y \sqrt{1+x^2})$